# Many elements not available on Xamarin Admob SDK

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to migrate to adaptive banner but i cant find some methods on the latest available ADmob sdk on Xamarin like:

```
AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(context, width)
```

, also for native Ads MediaContent its not available.

are there any tricks to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

however the code for GetCurrentOrientationBannerAdSizeWithWidth , to do Adaptive banners is the following .

```
 public static AdSize GetCurrentOrientationBannerAdSizeWithWidth(Context var0, int adWidth, int var2=50, int var3=0)
    {
        if (var0 == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            Resources var4;
            if ((var4 = (var0.ApplicationContext != null ? var0.ApplicationContext : var0).Resources) == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayMetrics var5;
                if ((var5 = var4.DisplayMetrics) == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    Configuration var6;
                    if ((var6 = var4.Configuration) == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int var7=2;
                        switch( var6.Orientation)
                        {
                            case Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Undefined: var7 = 0;break;
                            case Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Portrait: var7 = 1; break;
                            case Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape: var7 = 2; break;
                            case Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Square: var7 = 3; break;

                        }
                        if (var3 == 0)
                        {
                            var3 = var7;
                        }

                        int var8 = var3 == var7 ? (int)Math.Round((float)var5.HeightPixels / var5.Density) : (int)Math.Round((float)var5.WidthPixels / var5.Density);
                        int var9 = (int)Math.Min(90, Math.Round((float)var8 * 0.15F));
                        int var10;
                        if (adWidth > 655)
                        {

                            var10 =(int) Math.Round((float)adWidth / 728.0F * 90.0F);
                        }
                        else if (adWidth > 632)
                        {
                            var10 = 81;
                        }
                        else if (adWidth > 526)
                        {
                            var10 = (int)Math.Round((float)adWidth / 468.0F * 60.0F);
                        }
                        else if (adWidth > 432)
                        {
                            var10 = 68;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var10 = (int)Math.Round((float)adWidth / 320.0F * 50.0F);
                        }

                        var10 = Math.Max(Math.Min(var10, var9), 50);
                        return new AdSize(adWidth, var10);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well..... an hour after this post , Microsoft released an update on Nuget for Admob Sdk  support all googe ads new features. (sometimes its useful if someone is listening).

Answer (score 0):

[ShouldDelayBannerRenderingListenerImplementor Xamarin AdMob SDK 118.1.1 Building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61604669/shoulddelaybannerrenderinglistenerimplementor-xamarin-admob-sdk-118-1-1-building)

topic about Xamarin ADMOB SDk 118-1-1-preview building error